# Source and medium as hidden fields in a form

Tags: google-analytics

I asked this question in other forums, and didn't have a solution so far.

I would like to have Google Analytics' source and medium added in every form sent by my websites, as hidden fields.

I use WordPress, and the plugings that I commonly use for contact forms are Contact Form 7 and Fast Secure Contact Form.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

-- Gabriel

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a way.

It used to be that channel attribution was computed in the GA tracking code in the client, and you could extract it from the cookie values. However since Google has switched to the measurement protocol (which is what's behind both analytics.js and gtag.js) attribution is determined on the Google servers and there is no really feasible way to get the information in realtime to include it in a form.

You could create a script that emulates GA attribution, but the [rules are somewhat complex](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6205762?hl=en) and it is unlikey you would get an exact match.

Another way (which, if you are in Europe, might bring you in conflict with the new privacy guidelines from march on) would be to save a unique token with the form, send the same token as custom dimension to Google Analytics, and then join the information after the fact via the API. Some time ago I [described the process in a tutorial](http://www.flesheatingarthropods.org/import-ga-information-to-salesforce-part-1/), and even if this is for salesforce (and the specific code most certainly obsolete) it describes the problem and the solution somewhat exhaustively.

Comment: Thanks a HUGE lot! Now I understand clearly what is the problem, and your workaround sounds great too.